# Does Sam Adams sell its 'White Christmas' beer in six-packs?

Tags: distribution

Does Sam Adams sell its 'White Christmas' beer in six-packs?

I've only seen it included as part of its holiday sampler 12-pack. Never as its own standalone six-pack.

If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, they do!

You can find it online at [Binny's](http://www.binnys.com/beer/Sam_Adams_White_Christmas_Ale_49880.html), for example ($9.99).